# NSAttributedString on UITableViewCell causes performance issues

Tags: objective-c, rendering, nsattributedstring

I'm using AttributedStrings on cells, for displaying stocks details. 
When the amount is positive the text is green, and negative red.

Plus currency symbols, and different up and down image indicators on the attributedString.

This causes performance issues, scrolling is really buggy.

Is there a better option then attributedString? better rendering?

[image]

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Is there any way to solve this problem.

Comment: I used Facebook async display to solve this..

Answer (score 0):

Is the calculation of the numbers in every cell in the mainqueue? If it is, try moving it to a background queue and dispatch the UI painting to the main

Answer (score 0):

Keep the creation of `NSAttributedString` in your Model class. That way the creation of attributedString only happens for the first time and will be stored in the model array. We just need to assign it in the `cellForRow` instead of creating it every time.